# loading url to bootstrap modal using ajax in Laravel not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

In Laravel -Controller name is **ProductController**, method is **showproductinmodal** .
I tried this, javascript code it worked.

Web Route:

```
Route::get('admin/product/show/{id}', 'Admin\ProductController@showproductinmodal');
```

JS:

```
<script>
            $('.showinfo').click(function(){

            var productid = $(this).data('id');

            // AJAX request
            $(".modal-body").load("{{URL::to('admin/product/show/')}}"+"/"+productid);


            });            
</script>
```

Url loaded and returned some text to modal.
But this Javascript code not worked, i want to use code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.showinfo').click(function(){

   var productid = $(this).data('id');

   // AJAX request
   $.ajax({
    url: '{{route('admin.showproductinmodal')}}',
    type: 'post',
    data: {id: productid},
    success: function(response){ 
      // Add response in Modal body
      $('.modal-body').html(response);

    }
  });
 });
});
```

My web route code

```
Route::post('admin/product/show/', 'Admin\ProductController@showproductinmodal')->name('admin.showproductinmodal');
```

My Controller code:

```
public function showproductinmodal(Request $id)
    {
        return "Your test id:" . $id;
    }
```

My a tag

```
<a  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaldemo3"  data-id="15" class="showinfo">Any ID test</a>
```

Modal works normal, pops up when I use first javascript code everything works ok data loading, but second javascript code is necessary for me. I inserted alert also in $.ajax request but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are missing crsf token in you case:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Set csrf token for ajax call once then call N number of ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.showinfo').click(function () {
        var productid = $(this).data('id');
        let url = "{!! route('admin.showproductinmodal') !!}"
        // AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            data: { 
                id: productid 
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // Add response in Modal body
                $('.modal-body').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And it will me more better, if you will use bootstrap model event, and use base url with javascript global variable.